# How to make windows 7 to support Microsoft.Windows.Themes.SystemDropShadowChrome class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, selenium

I have used SystemDropShadowChrome theme on my combobox for styling but its throwing XamlParser Exception.
But it is working fine in windows 8.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aero theme is inbuild in Windows8,you need to Add aero theme for windows 7.